# Sending "this" radio button element parameter to function in Google Apps script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have a custom sidebar generated via Apps Script on a Google Sheet.

The custom sidebar html contains a form and fieldset with 5 radio input elements, all with onchange events:

```
google.script.run.viewOptionsFormRadioChange(this);
```

Here's the full form HTML:

```
<form id="viewOptionsForm">
      <fieldset class="viewOptionsFieldset">
        <input type="radio" id="all" name="viewOptionsRadio" value="All"  checked="checked" onchange='google.script.run.viewOptionsFormRadioChange(this);' >
        <label for="all">All</label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="firstImport" name="viewOptionsRadio" value="First Import" onchange='google.script.run.viewOptionsFormRadioChange(this);'>
        <label for="firstImport">First Import</label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="secondImport" name="viewOptionsRadio" value="Second Import" onchange='google.script.run.viewOptionsFormRadioChange(this);'>
        <label for="secondImport">Second Import</label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="compositionLinking" name="viewOptionsRadio" value="Composition Linking" onchange='google.script.run.viewOptionsFormRadioChange(this);'>
        <label for="compositionLinking">Composition Linking</label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="underTheHood" name="viewOptionsRadio" value="Under the Hood" onchange='google.script.run.viewOptionsFormRadioChange(this);'>
        <label for="underTheHood">Under the Hood</label>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
```

I then have a function "viewOptionsFormRadioChange":

```
function viewOptionsFormRadioChange(checkbox) {

    if(checkbox.checked == true){
      if(checkbox.attr('id') == "underTheHood") {
        SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("underTheHood Selected", "Title", 15);
      }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get it so the toast notification appears when I select the Under the Hood radio button, however the "this" element parameter doesn't appear to be coming through as parameter variable: checkbox since the above doesn't work.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Thanks either way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that in your script, how about modifying `this` to `this.value` or `this.id`? It seems that in this case, `this` cannot be parsed. So, when your script is modified, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, your HTML is modified.

```html
<form id="viewOptionsForm">
  <fieldset class="viewOptionsFieldset">
    <input type="radio" id="all" name="viewOptionsRadio" value="All"  checked="checked" onchange='google.script.run.viewOptionsFormRadioChange(this.value);' >
    <label for="all">All</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="firstImport" name="viewOptionsRadio" value="First Import" onchange='google.script.run.viewOptionsFormRadioChange(this.value);'>
    <label for="firstImport">First Import</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="secondImport" name="viewOptionsRadio" value="Second Import" onchange='google.script.run.viewOptionsFormRadioChange(this.value);'>
    <label for="secondImport">Second Import</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="compositionLinking" name="viewOptionsRadio" value="Composition Linking" onchange='google.script.run.viewOptionsFormRadioChange(this.value);'>
    <label for="compositionLinking">Composition Linking</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="underTheHood" name="viewOptionsRadio" value="Under the Hood" onchange='google.script.run.viewOptionsFormRadioChange(this.value);'>
    <label for="underTheHood">Under the Hood</label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

But, in this case, the returned value is the string value like `First Import`, `Second Import`,,,. So, your Google Apps Script might be required to be modified as follows.

```js
function viewOptionsFormRadioChange(checkbox) {
  if(checkbox == "Under the Hood") {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("underTheHood Selected", "Title", 15);
  }
}
```

By this modification, when you check "Under the Hood", `toast()` is run.

#### Note:

- If you want to use the value of `id`, please moidify `this.value` to `this.id`. By this, you can use the value of ID in your HTML tag. It's like `if(checkbox == "underTheHood") {,,,}` instead of `if(checkbox == "Under the Hood") {,,,}`.

Comment: Thankyou! That does the trick - I initially avoided trying to pass the id or value, and thought I had to be passing the whole element to get .checked, as I mistakenly believed "onchange" would trigger - both for the radio button that was deselected as well as the one that was selected. Many thanks for the quick response and solution!

Comment: @JackPDLTD Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. In the case of the radio button, your approach can be used. For example, if the checkboxes can be checked multiple, populating and sending the values of all checkboxes might be useful by clicking a button.